# Line 16 wont run properly (VBS)

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to make a program BUT whenever i run this .VBS file it says line 16 has an error, iv tried most things like putting it into a different directory, but it didn't work... rewording. renaming the file. AND just making it put the file into the designated place.

I'm expecting it to Copy the program to the C:\Windows\ directory, but its not realy copying it. iv also tried using "MoveFile" but it still didn't work.

THE CODE:

```
DIM FSO, MyFile
Set oShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )


''' runs file
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """SSS.bat""", 1, True

''' Alert Box
z=MsgBox("Finished.", 0+64, "Windows Alert!!!")
WScript.Sleep(1)
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """111.bat""", 1, True
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """file.bat""", 1, True


'''copy file to Windows
FSO.CopyFile "program.txt","C:\Windows\"
FSO.MoveFolder "C:\Windows\program.txt","C:\Windows\System32\program.exe"
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """C:\Windows\System32\program.exe""", 1, True
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is likely happening because you are trying to use the FSO.CopyFile method before you've created the FSO object. To fix the error, you should add the following line of code before using FSO.CopyFile:

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```